# How to highlight Tree path of selected node in TreeView control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I want to highlight TreePath till root node of the selected Node.

```
 protected void Trv_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HighlightPath(Trv.SelectedNode);
        }
 private void HighlightPath(TreeNode node)
        {
           //  node.["style"] = "color: orange";
            if (node.Parent != null)
            HighlightPath(node.Parent);

        }
```

How Can I highLight path or change parent node color till root level? Please help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HighlightPath(TreeView1.SelectedNode);
}
private void HighlightPath(TreeNode node)
{
    //  node.["style"] = "color: orange";
    node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
    node.Text = "<div style='color:orange'>" + node.Text + "</div>";
    if (node.Parent != null)
        HighlightPath(node.Parent);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
node.addcss["forecolor"]="color:orange";
```