# How to select(change) and deselect TreeNode full path in Treeview ASP.NET

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, treeview, treenode

I am working on asp.net application which has a TreeView. I am binding my Treeview from database. So my TreeView has several nodes. For example:

```
  Node1
    Node2
      Node3
        Node4
    Node5
    Node6
      Node7 
        Node8
```

Now, I want if I select any node I want to highlight full path of that node. So for example if I select **Node4**, I want to change the color(backcolor) of it's full path which is **Node4-Node3-Node2-Node1**.

If I select any other node after this I want the previous selected nodes to be same again and selected node path must be highlighted. After searching alot, I only found this

[How to highlight Tree path of selected node in TreeView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370564/how-to-highlight-tree-path-of-selected-node-in-treeview-control)

But when I do that I am not able to click any node and also deselect functionality doesn't work.

```
  protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       TreeView1.SelectedNodeStyle.CssClass = "treenodeSelected";


        HighlightPath(TreeView1.SelectedNode);

    }

    private void HighlightPath(TreeNode node)
    {
        node.Text = "<td class='treenodeSelected'>" + node.Text + "</td>";;
        if (node.Parent != null)
            HighlightPath(node.Parent);
    }
```

Please help me with this. I want to change only the back color of my TreeNode's full path(user can see that what path he has selected).

PS: adding any div's, span in Node Text not working properly.

Comment: Consider doing this with jquery, you can reach the parent of a child (and so on) relativey easy.

Comment: I can reach to the parent in code behind but it's just there is no property define to change css of particular node. How can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: @Rebeca, this is a good approach, check it out. http://forums.asp.net/t/1984928.aspx?Treeview+checked+and+unchecked+using+Jquery

Comment: @JCM, Working on the approach suggested by you. Will update you soon. Thank you so much:)